# Unable to send form data to mail using PHP mailer

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

I need to send form data to mail in tabular format. for this i'm using using PHPMailer. when I am trying to display values that are selected by user it only display as array. can somebody help me to find what is wrong in this code?

Below is the part of HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Favorite_Drink[]" value="Vodka">Vodka
<input type="checkbox" name="Favorite_Drink[]" value="Vodka">Vodka
<input type="checkbox" name="Favorite_Drink[]" value="Bear">Bear
```

Here is PHP part

```
$Favorite_Drink = $_POST['Favorite_Drink'];
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'd11288@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('a11288@gmail.com', 'User');
$mail->addAddress('al@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('a11288@gmail.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('a11288@gmail.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@arshad.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
//$mail->Body    = "Name of patient is ";
//$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = ' Test';
$mail->Body    = <<<EOF
<html><body>

    <br>
    <table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
        <tr style='background: #eee;'>
            <td>Favorite_Drink </td>
            <td> $Favorite_Drink</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
EOF;

            //Altbody is used to display plain text message for those email viewers which are not HTML compatible

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$Favorite_Drink = $_POST['Favorite_Drink'];` - this variable gets array of data from form.
`<td> $Favorite_Drink</td>` - if you want print array as text you should, use something like this implode(', ', $Favorite_Drink)

Comment: This answer is correct - you can't print an array directly, you need to process each of its elements. I think phpLover needs to try a bit harder...